# How would I read response status into feature file from another feature file in karate

Tags: karate

I am calling feature file B from feature file A in API automation. I want response status (e.g. -200, 201,400..) return in feature A. any idea how can I do with karate framework.

Answer (score 0):

This will be automatically available as a variable called `responseStatus`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsestatus

```
* def result = call read('B.feature')
* match result.responseStatus == 200
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for quick response.